# How to send image data in one viewController to the other viewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making a clock app, and I want to give the users choosing a several background images.(By clicking a UIButton in settingViewController, then background image will be changed in MainViewController.) So, I use segue but it doesn't work. Here is the code.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let nav:UINavigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
    let mainVC:MainViewController = nav.visibleViewController as! MainViewController
    //let mainVC: MainViewController = segue.destination as! MainViewController

    if bg1Button.isSelected == true {
        mainVC.bgImg.image = UIImage(named: "bg1.jpg")
    } else if bg2Button.isSelected == true {
        mainVC.bgImg.image = UIImage(named: "bg2.jpg")
    } else if bg3Button.isSelected == true {
        mainVC.bgImg.image = UIImage(named: "bg3.jpeg")
    } else if bg4Button.isSelected == true {
        mainVC.bgImg.image = UIImage(named: "bg4.jpg")
    } else if bg5Button.isSelected == true {
        mainVC.bgImg.image = UIImage(named: "bg5.png")
    } else if bg6Button.isSelected == true {
        mainVC.bgImg.image = UIImage(named: "bg6.png")
    } else if bg7Button.isSelected == true {
        mainVC.bgImg.image = UIImage(named: "bg7.jpg")
    }
}
```

I made a breakPoint, and I realize that when it get in the 'if', it didn't check anything and just get out. I don't know why. Please give me an advice. Thank you:)

Comment: When you click button do you set the button property to bg1Button.isSelected = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the image into Data like this :-

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) as? NSData
```

Pass the data to nextVC :-

```
 mainVC.imageData = data
```

Show image like this :-

```
let imagePt = UIImage(data: (imageData as! NSData) as Data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You convert your UIImage in NSData format and add in a dictionary or array, transfer this to MainViewController. There put NSData in UIImageView.